# Control swf (flash) live background

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am trying to make live Flash background which can be controlled by buttons outside the SWF (from the HTML page).

I am using dreamweaver, so I want to create buttons which will trigger `gotoAndPlay()`.

The idea is to make the background react on users action. Lets say user press button "Beach" and background will smoothly animate.

Does anyone has an idea how I can make it work?

Comment: You can do that using [`ExternalInterface`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cb2.html) ... try to write something and if you still have problem, then post it here.

Comment: I don't know if you are using ActionScript 2 or 3, that's why I put the ActionScript tag.